# SED Challenge - Add line on condition

Tags: shell, awk, sed

"sed" is giving me a headace, so I post the issue here. And yes, it should be done with sed, to be executed in a script.

https://www.jdoodle.com/a/6ZL5

The idea is to alter a text file that consists of blocks of about 30 lines. Each block starts with "StartLine" is separated form the next by one empty line (AD-search result).
Within each block, I need to add the line "AddMe" after the line "AlwaysExists", **BUT ONLY** if in this block there not already exists a line that contains "NoNoNo". So its adding on condition...
As a result, there should be either of those:

```
StartLine
AlwaysExists
NoNoNo  <--- Not added "AddMe", because "NoNoNo" exists
<Emply line>

StartLine
AlwaysExists
AddMe <--- Added, because NoNoNo here not exists
<Emply line>
```

The following is probably a working approach, but I cannot finish it so it works:

```
sed -i '/StartLine/,/^$/{
  <whatever is needed>
}' myfile.ldif
```

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.
Chris

EDIT:

```
sed '/StartLine/,/^$/{
    /NoNoNo/!{
        :loop
        N
        /NoNoNo/!{
            $!b loop
            a\
AddMe
        }
    }
}' /uploads/ldif.txt
```

...this only adds AddMe once at the bottom...

EDIT #2 Example Input file:

```
StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
NoNoNo
Dummy2

StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
Dummy2

StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
NoNoNo
Dummy2

StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
Dummy2
```

**Solution with awk**: I needed to change the script, because of a small missunderstanding. But the approach as suggested by @Luuk is still working! Thanks at you all for giving me that hint!

```
awk '
  BEGIN{ x=0 }
    function prut() {
      for(i=0; i < length(s); i++) {
        print s[i]
        if (a!=1 && s[i]~/InsertHere/) {
          print "Addme"
          a=0
          }
      }
      x=0; a=0;  delete(s)
    }
    {s[x]=$0; x++}
    /NoNoNo-/{a=1}
    {
      if (length($0)<2){
        prut()
      }
    }
  END {
      prut()
  }
  ' file.ldif
```

Comment: `it should be done with sed, to be executed in a script` I do not think that is a reason, anything can be "executed in a script",

Comment: Its not a reason, just a requirement. AND ist says "should"... :-)

Comment: "_**The following is probably a working approach, but I cannot finish it so it works**_"  There should be an election for best stackoverflow statement of the year, and this statement would be high on the list (IMHO)  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED (Because of an extended LDFIF.txt):

When having an input file like:

```
StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
NoNoNo
Dummy2

StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
Dummy2

StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
NoNoNo
Dummy2

StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
Dummy2
```

I would use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ x=0 }
     function prut() {
         for(i=1; i<=length(s); i++) {
             print s[i]
             if  (a!=1 && s[i]~/AlwaysExists/) {
                 print "AddMe"
                 a=0
             }
         }
         x=0; a=0;  delete(s)
     }
     /StartLine/{ x=1 }
     (x>0) && /NoNoNo/ { a=1 }
     (x>0){ s[x]=$0; x++ }
     length($1)<2{
         prut()
     }
     END {
         prut()
     }
    ' ldif.txt | sed -e ''
```

It produces:

```
StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
NoNoNo
Dummy2

StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
AddMe
Dummy2

StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
NoNoNo
Dummy2

StartLine
Dummy1
AlwaysExists
AddMe
Dummy2
```

and it even includes a use of `sed`....

Comment: I tried your code and it throws "scalar is not an array" at line 10. I tested your code online and there it works. Seems to be the Version of my awk, its GNU AWK 4.2.1. vs. online it is 5.3. I try to get a newer version of awk, but if not possible, can I workaround that somehow?

Comment: Version 5.3 (for Windows) is available here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/  (I am using 5.1 currently, installed via [chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/gawk)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use range. As long as there is always an empty line:

```
sed '
    /StartLine/ {
:a
        N
        /\n$/!ba
    }
    /NoNoNo/!s/AlwaysExists/&\nAddMe/
' inputfile
```

Note that I am assuming that `AlwaysExists` is a regex that matches the entire line. If it doesn't, you will need to adjust the expression so that it does.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `-n` and a slight tweak: if the `AlwaysExists` line has more to it perhaps change it to  `!s/AlwaysExists[^\n]*/&\nAddMe/` or if GNU sed use `!s/AlwaysExists.*/\nAddMe/m`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, different approach! Using JDoodle to test, dunno which linux they use. I removed "-n", but no success yet... The uploaded source file (cat /upload/ldif.txt) is:
    StartLine
    Dummy1
    AlwaysExists
    NoNoNo
    Dummy2

    StartLine
    Dummy1
    AlwaysExists
    Dummy2

    StartLine
    Dummy1
    AlwaysExists
    NoNoNo
    Dummy2

    StartLine
    Dummy1
    AlwaysExists
    Dummy2

Comment: @potong thanks, I started out with something else and didn't notice it was no longer needed